# wp_add_inline_script without dependency

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have a javascript snippet that I want to inject into the footer of the page. It's a tracking code, let's say similar to Google analytics.  It has no dependencies, it's a standalone snippet.

I can do something like this

```
function render_tracking_code(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'depends-js', 'https://rdiv.com/dummy.js', array(), '0.01', true );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'depends-js', 'aWholeBunchOfJavascriptCode' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'render_tracking_code' );
```

Seems a little stupid (dummy.js is a blank file), but works. Is there a way to skip the dependency?

Answer (score 43):

### `wp_add_inline_style()` - without dependency

The `wp_add_inline_style()` can be used without a source file dependency.

Here's an [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/282868/26350) from @Flix:

```
wp_register_style( 'dummy-handle', false );
wp_enqueue_style( 'dummy-handle' );
wp_add_inline_style( 'dummy-handle', '* { color: red; }' );
```

where we would hook this into the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

### `wp_add_inline_script()` - without dependency

According to ticket [#43565](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44551), similar will be supported for `wp_add_inline_script()` in version <strike>`4.9.9`</strike> `5.0` (thanks to @MarcioDuarte, @dev101 and @DaveRomsey for the verification in comments):

```
wp_register_script( 'dummy-handle-header', '' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'dummy-handle-header' );
wp_add_inline_script( 'dummy-handle-header', 'console.log( "header" );' );
```

that will display the following in the *header*, i.e.between the `<head>...</head>` tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
console.log( "header" );
</script>
```

To display it in the *footer*:

```
wp_register_script( 'dummy-handle-footer', '', [], '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'dummy-handle-footer'  );
wp_add_inline_script( 'dummy-handle-footer', 'console.log( "footer" );' );
```

The default of `$position` input argument in `wp_add_inline_script()` is `'after'`. The `'before'` value prints it above `'after'`.

Comment: The `wp_add_inline_script()` without dependency is still being considered for 4.9.9, it doesn't necessarily mean that it will be added. So it's wise to wait for confirmation before using this feature.

Comment: We're good to go as of [WP 5.0](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44551#comment:8).

Comment: Someone deleted my comment from here (I confirmed birgire's answere that it actually works in WP 5.0+), and a month later I actually needed this code again, googled, found this answer, swept at a glance, not finding my comment, and moved on to other results. Just after an hour, I came back here, realizing that this was the answer I was looking for! To moderator: please DO NOT delete my useful comments, they serve ME as well as future references and reminders, not just for others. Thank you.

Comment: Unluckily I have to stick with Version 4.9.x.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** WordPress added  support for adding inline scripts and styles without a dependency in v5.0. See [@birgire's answer for](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/311279/2807) implementations.

When using `wp_add_inline_script()`, `WP_Scripts::print_inline_script()` will ultimately be used to output inline scripts. By design, `print_inline_script()` requires a valid dependency, `$handle`.

Since there is no dependency in this case, `wp_add_inline_script()` is not the right tool for the job. Instead of creating a fake dependency file (and undesirable additional HTTP request), use `wp_head` or `wp_footer` to output the inline script:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_add_inline_script' );
function wpse_add_inline_script() {
  echo '<script>' . PHP_EOL;

  // aWholeBunchOfJavascriptCode

  echo '</script>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Generally, JavaScript should be added to a `.js` file and enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script()` on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Data can be made available to the script using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Sometimes it may still be necessary to add a script inline though.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to create a function that echoes your script inside a `<script>` tag, and hook it to the [`wp_print_footer_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_footer_scripts/) action. You should take care to escape anything that you don't strictly control, but this a generally safe and easy method otherwise.

For example:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () { 
    ?>
    <script>
        (function myFunction() { 
            /* your code here */
        })();
    </script>
<?php 
} );
```