# enqueue hover function

Tags: php, hooks, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to enqueue a hover function in my functios.php of my child theme, so that when hovering over a title, a div with a text will be visible. The code I am using is this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'home_game', 20);  

function home_game(){
?>
<script>
    let title1 = document.getElementById("home-title1");
    title1.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
    title1.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);
    
    function mouseOver(){
    document.getElementById('title-box').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('home-box1').style.display = 'block';
}
    function mouseOut(){
    document.getElementById('title-box').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('home-box1').style.display = 'none';
}
    
</script>

<?php
}
```

It works in my fiddle so I guess the problem is in my php, I am fairly new with it... Any help or clue will be very appreciated!

fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/rvoLc3ph/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your JS to a file in your child theme `/js/example.js`, then enqueue it like this:

```
//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', [], '1.0.0', true );
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the styles inline using this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_home_game', 20 );
function wpse_home_game() {
    wp_register_script( 'home-game', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'home-game' );

    $script = "

    let title1 = document.getElementById('home-title1');

    // Check if title1 was present before wiring up event listeners.
    if ( null !== title1 )  {
        title1.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
        title1.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);
    }

    function mouseOver(){
        document.getElementById('title-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('home-box1').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function mouseOut(){
        document.getElementById('title-box').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('home-box1').style.display = 'none';
    }

    ";

    wp_add_inline_script( 'home-game', $script );
}
```

See for source of this trick from @birgire [wp_add_inline_script without dependency](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298762/wp-add-inline-script-without-dependency)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer Dave, I ended up adding the JS in a different file as you suggested first. I knew I could do this but I did not investigate it yet, I was trying to write all in functions.php and I did not understand why I could not.... Very interesting trick for adding the styles inline, unfortunately I could not make it work but I will study more about it!

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with JS, remember that it's sketchy on mobile phones and doesn't always work.  You might consider instead using a CSS 'tooltips' type of approach, which is pretty much just straight CSS with a hidden DIV that shows on hover.

You can play around with the generators, one of which is here:

https://doodlenerd.com/css-element/tooltip-generator

If you post more about how you're creating the title and the text within the DIV I may be able to suggest easy ways of crafting them on the fly too.....

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Trisha, in my case I wanted to style it very specifically so it would have been extra work to make it only with CSS tooltips, but I will keep the trick in mind