# How to add some basic inline CSS using existing plugin or theme?

Tags: plugin-development, css, optimization

Sometimes you have a theme or a very lightweight WordPress plugin (like a single PHP file) and you want to add some CSS easily without having to [load more files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-do-i-add-css-options-to-my-plugin-without-using-inline-styles) or folders, etc.

How can you add some basic inline CSS rules using an existing script in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using `wp_add_inline_style` ... here is the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/).

A great example I found on a [public Gist](https://gist.github.com/neilgee/bdf621baa3d535c97d9d):

```
<?php

//Adding CSS inline style to an existing CSS stylesheet
function wpb_add_inline_css() {

        //All the user input CSS settings as set in the plugin settings
        $slicknav_custom_css = "
            @media screen and (max-width: {$ng_slicknav_width}px) {
                {$ng_slicknav_menu} {
                  display: none;
               }
               .slicknav_menu {
                  display: block;
                  background: {$ng_slicknav_background};
               }
               .slicknav_btn {
                  background-color:{$ng_slicknav_button};
                  float:{$ng_slicknav_button_position};
               }
           }";

  //Add the above custom CSS via wp_add_inline_style
  wp_add_inline_style( 'slicknavcss', $slicknav_custom_css ); //Pass the variable into the main style sheet ID

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_add_inline_css' ); //Enqueue the CSS style
```

And if your plugin doesn't have an existing stylesheet, you can register a "dummy" one [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168867/using-wp-add-inline-style-without-a-stylesheet):

```
wp_register_style( 'dummy-handle', false );
wp_enqueue_style( 'dummy-handle' );

wp_add_inline_style( 'dummy-handle', '* { color: red; }' );
```